# File Type Assoc using batch

Tags: batch-file

i am looking for validating and then registering a specific FTA through batch. Any thoughts?

E.g. `IF ['assoc .txt'] == [] goto :REGFTA`

```
:ENDREGFTA
EXIT /B

:REGFTA
assoc .txt=txtfile
```

OR

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=3 DELIMS= " %%A in ('ASSOC .TXT  |FINDSTR "NOT"') DO (
IF /I "%%A" EQU "not" (assoc .txt=txtfile) Else (Echo FTA Exist)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
assoc .txt >nul 2>&1 || assoc .txt=txtfile
```

assoc with invalid extension returns errorlevel 1 so you can use [conditional execution](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/condexec.php)